# jQuery Accordian - Help making only one top level tab open at a time. When one is clicked to open other tab closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a great accordion utility from [CodyHouse](https://codyhouse.co/demo/multi-level-accordion-menu/index.html). I'm trying to extend the functionality to only allow one top level accordion tab to be open at a time. When another one is clicked the open tab closes and the newly clicked tab opens. Currently all tabs can be open at a time. I appreciate any help... Please see my attached code.

```js
/* Modernizr 2.8.3 (Custom Build) | MIT & BSD
 * Build: http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-flexbox-hsla-multiplebgs-opacity-rgba-textshadow-cssanimations-csscolumns-generatedcontent-cssgradients-cssreflections-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-applicationcache-canvas-canvastext-draganddrop-hashchange-history-audio-video-indexeddb-input-inputtypes-localstorage-postmessage-sessionstorage-websockets-websqldatabase-webworkers-geolocation-inlinesvg-smil-svg-svgclippaths-touch-webgl-shiv-cssclasses-addtest-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes-load
 */
;window.Modernizr=function(a,b,c){function C(a){j.cssText=a}function D(a,b){return C(n.join(a+";")+(b||""))}function E(a,b){return typeof a===b}function F(a,b){return!!~(""+a).indexOf(b)}function G(a,b){for(var d in a){var e=a[d];if(!F(e,"-")&&j[e]!==c)return b=="pfx"?e:!0}return!1}function H(a,b,d){for(var e in a){var f=b[a[e]];if(f!==c)return d===!1?a[e]:E(f,"function")?f.bind(d||b):f}return!1}function I(a,b,c){var d=a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.slice(1),e=(a+" "+p.join(d+" ")+d).split(" ");return E(b,"string")||E(b,"undefined")?G(e,b):(e=(a+" "+q.join(d+" ")+d).split(" "),H(e,b,c))}function J(){e.input=function(c){for(var d=0,e=c.length;d<e;d++)u[c[d]]=c[d]in k;return u.list&&(u.list=!!b.createElement("datalist")&&!!a.HTMLDataListElement),u}("autocomplete autofocus list placeholder max min multiple pattern required step".split(" ")),e.inputtypes=function(a){for(var d=0,e,f,h,i=a.length;d<i;d++)k.setAttribute("type",f=a[d]),e=k.type!=="text",e&&(k.value=l,k.style.cssText="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;",/^range$/.test(f)&&k.style.WebkitAppearance!==c?(g.appendChild(k),h=b.defaultView,e=h.getComputedStyle&&h.getComputedStyle(k,null).WebkitAppearance!=="textfield"&&k.offsetHeight!==0,g.removeChild(k)):/^(search|tel)$/.test(f)||(/^(url|email)$/.test(f)?e=k.checkValidity&&k.checkValidity()===!1:e=k.value!=l)),t[a[d]]=!!e;return t}("search tel url email datetime date month week time datetime-local number range color".split(" "))}var d="2.8.3",e={},f=!0,g=b.documentElement,h="modernizr",i=b.createElement(h),j=i.style,k=b.createElement("input"),l=":)",m={}.toString,n=" -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- ".split(" "),o="Webkit Moz O ms",p=o.split(" "),q=o.toLowerCase().split(" "),r={svg:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"},s={},t={},u={},v=[],w=v.slice,x,y=function(a,c,d,e){var f,i,j,k,l=b.createElement("div"),m=b.body,n=m||b.createElement("body");if(parseInt(d,10))while(d--)j=b.createElement("div"),j.id=e?e[d]:h+(d+1),l.appendChild(j);return f=["&#173;",'<style id="s',h,'">',a,"</style>"].join(""),l.id=h,(m?l:n).innerHTML+=f,n.appendChild(l),m||(n.style.background="",n.style.overflow="hidden",k=g.style.overflow,g.style.overflow="hidden",g.appendChild(n)),i=c(l,a),m?l.parentNode.removeChild(l):(n.parentNode.removeChild(n),g.style.overflow=k),!!i},z=function(){function d(d,e){e=e||b.createElement(a[d]||"div"),d="on"+d;var f=d in e;return f||(e.setAttribute||(e=b.createElement("div")),e.setAttribute&&e.removeAttribute&&(e.setAttribute(d,""),f=E(e[d],"function"),E(e[d],"undefined")||(e[d]=c),e.removeAttribute(d))),e=null,f}var a={select:"input",change:"input",submit:"form",reset:"form",error:"img",load:"img",abort:"img"};return d}(),A={}.hasOwnProperty,B;!E(A,"undefined")&&!E(A.call,"undefined")?B=function(a,b){return A.call(a,b)}:B=function(a,b){return b in a&&E(a.constructor.prototype[b],"undefined")},Function.prototype.bind||(Function.prototype.bind=function(b){var c=this;if(typeof c!="function")throw new TypeError;var d=w.call(arguments,1),e=function(){if(this instanceof e){var a=function(){};a.prototype=c.prototype;var f=new a,g=c.apply(f,d.concat(w.call(arguments)));return Object(g)===g?g:f}return c.apply(b,d.concat(w.call(arguments)))};return e}),s.flexbox=function(){return I("flexWrap")},s.canvas=function(){var a=b.createElement("canvas");return!!a.getContext&&!!a.getContext("2d")},s.canvastext=function(){return!!e.canvas&&!!E(b.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d").fillText,"function")},s.webgl=function(){return!!a.WebGLRenderingContext},s.touch=function(){var c;return"ontouchstart"in a||a.DocumentTouch&&b instanceof DocumentTouch?c=!0:y(["@media (",n.join("touch-enabled),("),h,")","{#modernizr{top:9px;position:absolute}}"].join(""),function(a){c=a.offsetTop===9}),c},s.geolocation=function(){return"geolocation"in navigator},s.postmessage=function(){return!!a.postMessage},s.websqldatabase=function(){return!!a.openDatabase},s.indexedDB=function(){return!!I("indexedDB",a)},s.hashchange=function(){return z("hashchange",a)&&(b.documentMode===c||b.documentMode>7)},s.history=function(){return!!a.history&&!!history.pushState},s.draganddrop=function(){var a=b.createElement("div");return"draggable"in a||"ondragstart"in a&&"ondrop"in a},s.websockets=function(){return"WebSocket"in a||"MozWebSocket"in a},s.rgba=function(){return C("background-color:rgba(150,255,150,.5)"),F(j.backgroundColor,"rgba")},s.hsla=function(){return C("background-color:hsla(120,40%,100%,.5)"),F(j.backgroundColor,"rgba")||F(j.backgroundColor,"hsla")},s.multiplebgs=function(){return C("background:url(https://),url(https://),red url(https://)"),/(url\s*\(.*?){3}/.test(j.background)},s.backgroundsize=function(){return I("backgroundSize")},s.borderimage=function(){return I("borderImage")},s.borderradius=function(){return I("borderRadius")},s.boxshadow=function(){return I("boxShadow")},s.textshadow=function(){return b.createElement("div").style.textShadow===""},s.opacity=function(){return D("opacity:.55"),/^0.55$/.test(j.opacity)},s.cssanimations=function(){return I("animationName")},s.csscolumns=function(){return I("columnCount")},s.cssgradients=function(){var a="background-image:",b="gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(white));",c="linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, white);";return C((a+"-webkit- ".split(" ").join(b+a)+n.join(c+a)).slice(0,-a.length)),F(j.backgroundImage,"gradient")},s.cssreflections=function(){return I("boxReflect")},s.csstransforms=function(){return!!I("transform")},s.csstransforms3d=function(){var a=!!I("perspective");return a&&"webkitPerspective"in g.style&&y("@media (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d){#modernizr{left:9px;position:absolute;height:3px;}}",function(b,c){a=b.offsetLeft===9&&b.offsetHeight===3}),a},s.csstransitions=function(){return I("transition")},s.fontface=function(){var a;return y('@font-face {font-family:"font";src:url("https://")}',function(c,d){var e=b.getElementById("smodernizr"),f=e.sheet||e.styleSheet,g=f?f.cssRules&&f.cssRules[0]?f.cssRules[0].cssText:f.cssText||"":"";a=/src/i.test(g)&&g.indexOf(d.split(" ")[0])===0}),a},s.generatedcontent=function(){var a;return y(["#",h,"{font:0/0 a}#",h,':after{content:"',l,'";visibility:hidden;font:3px/1 a}'].join(""),function(b){a=b.offsetHeight>=3}),a},s.video=function(){var a=b.createElement("video"),c=!1;try{if(c=!!a.canPlayType)c=new Boolean(c),c.ogg=a.canPlayType('video/ogg; codecs="theora"').replace(/^no$/,""),c.h264=a.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"').replace(/^no$/,""),c.webm=a.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"').replace(/^no$/,"")}catch(d){}return c},s.audio=function(){var a=b.createElement("audio"),c=!1;try{if(c=!!a.canPlayType)c=new Boolean(c),c.ogg=a.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"').replace(/^no$/,""),c.mp3=a.canPlayType("audio/mpeg;").replace(/^no$/,""),c.wav=a.canPlayType('audio/wav; codecs="1"').replace(/^no$/,""),c.m4a=(a.canPlayType("audio/x-m4a;")||a.canPlayType("audio/aac;")).replace(/^no$/,"")}catch(d){}return c},s.localstorage=function(){try{return localStorage.setItem(h,h),localStorage.removeItem(h),!0}catch(a){return!1}},s.sessionstorage=function(){try{return sessionStorage.setItem(h,h),sessionStorage.removeItem(h),!0}catch(a){return!1}},s.webworkers=function(){return!!a.Worker},s.applicationcache=function(){return!!a.applicationCache},s.svg=function(){return!!b.createElementNS&&!!b.createElementNS(r.svg,"svg").createSVGRect},s.inlinesvg=function(){var a=b.createElement("div");return a.innerHTML="<svg/>",(a.firstChild&&a.firstChild.namespaceURI)==r.svg},s.smil=function(){return!!b.createElementNS&&/SVGAnimate/.test(m.call(b.createElementNS(r.svg,"animate")))},s.svgclippaths=function(){return!!b.createElementNS&&/SVGClipPath/.test(m.call(b.createElementNS(r.svg,"clipPath")))};for(var K in s)B(s,K)&&(x=K.toLowerCase(),e[x]=s[K](),v.push((e[x]?"":"no-")+x));return e.input||J(),e.addTest=function(a,b){if(typeof a=="object")for(var d in a)B(a,d)&&e.addTest(d,a[d]);else{a=a.toLowerCase();if(e[a]!==c)return e;b=typeof b=="function"?b():b,typeof f!="undefined"&&f&&(g.className+=" "+(b?"":"no-")+a),e[a]=b}return e},C(""),i=k=null,function(a,b){function l(a,b){var c=a.createElement("p"),d=a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||a.documentElement;return c.innerHTML="x<style>"+b+"</style>",d.insertBefore(c.lastChild,d.firstChild)}function m(){var a=s.elements;return typeof a=="string"?a.split(" "):a}function n(a){var b=j[a[h]];return b||(b={},i++,a[h]=i,j[i]=b),b}function o(a,c,d){c||(c=b);if(k)return c.createElement(a);d||(d=n(c));var g;return d.cache[a]?g=d.cache[a].cloneNode():f.test(a)?g=(d.cache[a]=d.createElem(a)).cloneNode():g=d.createElem(a),g.canHaveChildren&&!e.test(a)&&!g.tagUrn?d.frag.appendChild(g):g}function p(a,c){a||(a=b);if(k)return a.createDocumentFragment();c=c||n(a);var d=c.frag.cloneNode(),e=0,f=m(),g=f.length;for(;e<g;e++)d.createElement(f[e]);return d}function q(a,b){b.cache||(b.cache={},b.createElem=a.createElement,b.createFrag=a.createDocumentFragment,b.frag=b.createFrag()),a.createElement=function(c){return s.shivMethods?o(c,a,b):b.createElem(c)},a.createDocumentFragment=Function("h,f","return function(){var n=f.cloneNode(),c=n.createElement;h.shivMethods&&("+m().join().replace(/[\w\-]+/g,function(a){return b.createElem(a),b.frag.createElement(a),'c("'+a+'")'})+");return n}")(s,b.frag)}function r(a){a||(a=b);var c=n(a);return s.shivCSS&&!g&&!c.hasCSS&&(c.hasCSS=!!l(a,"article,aside,dialog,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section{display:block}mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}template{display:none}")),k||q(a,c),a}var c="3.7.0",d=a.html5||{},e=/^<|^(?:button|map|select|textarea|object|iframe|option|optgroup)$/i,f=/^(?:a|b|code|div|fieldset|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|i|label|li|ol|p|q|span|strong|style|table|tbody|td|th|tr|ul)$/i,g,h="_html5shiv",i=0,j={},k;(function(){try{var a=b.createElement("a");a.innerHTML="<xyz></xyz>",g="hidden"in a,k=a.childNodes.length==1||function(){b.createElement("a");var a=b.createDocumentFragment();return typeof a.cloneNode=="undefined"||typeof a.createDocumentFragment=="undefined"||typeof a.createElement=="undefined"}()}catch(c){g=!0,k=!0}})();var s={elements:d.elements||"abbr article aside audio bdi canvas data datalist details dialog figcaption figure footer header hgroup main mark meter nav output progress section summary template time video",version:c,shivCSS:d.shivCSS!==!1,supportsUnknownElements:k,shivMethods:d.shivMethods!==!1,type:"default",shivDocument:r,createElement:o,createDocumentFragment:p};a.html5=s,r(b)}(this,b),e._version=d,e._prefixes=n,e._domPrefixes=q,e._cssomPrefixes=p,e.hasEvent=z,e.testProp=function(a){return G([a])},e.testAllProps=I,e.testStyles=y,e.prefixed=function(a,b,c){return b?I(a,b,c):I(a,"pfx")},g.className=g.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-js(\s|$)/,"$1$2")+(f?" js "+v.join(" "):""),e}(this,this.document),function(a,b,c){function d(a){return"[object Function]"==o.call(a)}function e(a){return"string"==typeof a}function f(){}function g(a){return!a||"loaded"==a||"complete"==a||"uninitialized"==a}function h(){var a=p.shift();q=1,a?a.t?m(function(){("c"==a.t?B.injectCss:B.injectJs)(a.s,0,a.a,a.x,a.e,1)},0):(a(),h()):q=0}function i(a,c,d,e,f,i,j){function k(b){if(!o&&g(l.readyState)&&(u.r=o=1,!q&&h(),l.onload=l.onreadystatechange=null,b)){"img"!=a&&m(function(){t.removeChild(l)},50);for(var d in y[c])y[c].hasOwnProperty(d)&&y[c][d].onload()}}var j=j||B.errorTimeout,l=b.createElement(a),o=0,r=0,u={t:d,s:c,e:f,a:i,x:j};1===y[c]&&(r=1,y[c]=[]),"object"==a?l.data=c:(l.src=c,l.type=a),l.width=l.height="0",l.onerror=l.onload=l.onreadystatechange=function(){k.call(this,r)},p.splice(e,0,u),"img"!=a&&(r||2===y[c]?(t.insertBefore(l,s?null:n),m(k,j)):y[c].push(l))}function j(a,b,c,d,f){return q=0,b=b||"j",e(a)?i("c"==b?v:u,a,b,this.i++,c,d,f):(p.splice(this.i++,0,a),1==p.length&&h()),this}function k(){var a=B;return a.loader={load:j,i:0},a}var l=b.documentElement,m=a.setTimeout,n=b.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],o={}.toString,p=[],q=0,r="MozAppearance"in l.style,s=r&&!!b.createRange().compareNode,t=s?l:n.parentNode,l=a.opera&&"[object Opera]"==o.call(a.opera),l=!!b.attachEvent&&!l,u=r?"object":l?"script":"img",v=l?"script":u,w=Array.isArray||function(a){return"[object Array]"==o.call(a)},x=[],y={},z={timeout:function(a,b){return b.length&&(a.timeout=b[0]),a}},A,B;B=function(a){function b(a){var a=a.split("!"),b=x.length,c=a.pop(),d=a.length,c={url:c,origUrl:c,prefixes:a},e,f,g;for(f=0;f<d;f++)g=a[f].split("="),(e=z[g.shift()])&&(c=e(c,g));for(f=0;f<b;f++)c=x[f](c);return c}function g(a,e,f,g,h){var i=b(a),j=i.autoCallback;i.url.split(".").pop().split("?").shift(),i.bypass||(e&&(e=d(e)?e:e[a]||e[g]||e[a.split("/").pop().split("?")[0]]),i.instead?i.instead(a,e,f,g,h):(y[i.url]?i.noexec=!0:y[i.url]=1,f.load(i.url,i.forceCSS||!i.forceJS&&"css"==i.url.split(".").pop().split("?").shift()?"c":c,i.noexec,i.attrs,i.timeout),(d(e)||d(j))&&f.load(function(){k(),e&&e(i.origUrl,h,g),j&&j(i.origUrl,h,g),y[i.url]=2})))}function h(a,b){function c(a,c){if(a){if(e(a))c||(j=function(){var a=[].slice.call(arguments);k.apply(this,a),l()}),g(a,j,b,0,h);else if(Object(a)===a)for(n in m=function(){var b=0,c;for(c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&b++;return b}(),a)a.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(!c&&!--m&&(d(j)?j=function(){var a=[].slice.call(arguments);k.apply(this,a),l()}:j[n]=function(a){return function(){var b=[].slice.call(arguments);a&&a.apply(this,b),l()}}(k[n])),g(a[n],j,b,n,h))}else!c&&l()}var h=!!a.test,i=a.load||a.both,j=a.callback||f,k=j,l=a.complete||f,m,n;c(h?a.yep:a.nope,!!i),i&&c(i)}var i,j,l=this.yepnope.loader;if(e(a))g(a,0,l,0);else if(w(a))for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)j=a[i],e(j)?g(j,0,l,0):w(j)?B(j):Object(j)===j&&h(j,l);else Object(a)===a&&h(a,l)},B.addPrefix=function(a,b){z[a]=b},B.addFilter=function(a){x.push(a)},B.errorTimeout=1e4,null==b.readyState&&b.addEventListener&&(b.readyState="loading",b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",A=function(){b.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",A,0),b.readyState="complete"},0)),a.yepnope=k(),a.yepnope.executeStack=h,a.yepnope.injectJs=function(a,c,d,e,i,j){var k=b.createElement("script"),l,o,e=e||B.errorTimeout;k.src=a;for(o in d)k.setAttribute(o,d[o]);c=j?h:c||f,k.onreadystatechange=k.onload=function(){!l&&g(k.readyState)&&(l=1,c(),k.onload=k.onreadystatechange=null)},m(function(){l||(l=1,c(1))},e),i?k.onload():n.parentNode.insertBefore(k,n)},a.yepnope.injectCss=function(a,c,d,e,g,i){var e=b.createElement("link"),j,c=i?h:c||f;e.href=a,e.rel="stylesheet",e.type="text/css";for(j in d)e.setAttribute(j,d[j]);g||(n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n),m(c,0))}}(this,document),Modernizr.load=function(){yepnope.apply(window,[].slice.call(arguments,0))};
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Jaldi", sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #f9f8f6;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
  color: #a0f6aa;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 2em auto 0;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  color: #6e2029;
  font-weight: bold;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3.2rem;
  }
}

input {
  font-family: "Jaldi", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.cd-accordion-menu {
  width: 35%;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width:440px;
  background: #4d5158;
  margin: 4em auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul {
  display: none;
}
.cd-accordion-menu li {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.cd-accordion-menu label, .cd-accordion-menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 18px 18px 18px 64px;
  background: #4d5158;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #555960;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.no-touch .cd-accordion-menu label:hover, .no-touch .cd-accordion-menu a:hover {
  background: #52565d;
}
.cd-accordion-menu label::before, .cd-accordion-menu label::after, .cd-accordion-menu a::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.cd-accordion-menu label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cd-accordion-menu label::before, .cd-accordion-menu label::after {
  background-image: url(../img/cd-icons.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.cd-accordion-menu label::before {
  left: 18px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
.cd-accordion-menu label::after {
  left: 41px;
  background-position: -16px 0;
}
.cd-accordion-menu li > a::after {
  left: 36px;
  background: url(../img/cd-iconsInternalLink.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  background-position: -32px 0;
}
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + ul,
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:nth-of-type(n) + ul {

  display: block;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul label,
.cd-accordion-menu li > a {
  background: #35383d;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #41444a;
  padding-left: 82px;
}
.no-touch .cd-accordion-menu ul label:hover, .no-touch
.cd-accordion-menu ul a:hover {
  background: #3c3f45;
}
.cd-accordion-menu > li:last-of-type > label,
.cd-accordion-menu > li:last-of-type > a,
.cd-accordion-menu > li > ul > li:last-of-type label,
.cd-accordion-menu > li > ul > li:last-of-type a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul label::before {
  left: 36px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul label::after,
.cd-accordion-menu ul a::after {
  left: 59px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul label,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul a {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::before {
  left: 54px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::after,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul a::after {
  left: 77px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a {
  padding-left: 118px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::before {
  left: 72px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::after,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a::after {
  left: 95px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .cd-accordion-menu label, .cd-accordion-menu a {
    padding: 5px 24px 5px 82px;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu label::before {
    left: 24px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu label::after {
    left: 53px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul label,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul a {
    padding-left: 106px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul label::before {
    left: 48px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul label::after,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul a::after {
    left: 77px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul label,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul a {
    padding-left: 130px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::before {
    left: 72px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::after,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul a::after {
    left: 101px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a {
    padding-left: 154px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::before {
    left: 96px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::after,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a::after {
    left: 125px;
  }
}
.cd-accordion-menu.animated label::before {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
span.textDesc{
 padding:10px;
 display:inline-block;
 background:#35383d;
}
span.textDesc a{
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#35383d;
 width:inherit;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0 2px 0 20px;
   display:inline-block;
   font:inherit;
 box-shadow:none;
}
span.textDesc a:link{
   background: url(../img/cd-iconsInternalLink.png) no-repeat 5px 3px;
   background-size:8%;
}
span.textDesc a:hover{
 color:lightgray;
   background: url(../img/cd-iconsInternalLink.png) no-repeat 5px 3px !important;
   background-color:transparent !important;
   background-size:8% !important;
   text-decoration:underline !important;
}
.last{
 border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jaldi:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css"> <!-- Animation style -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
   
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 class="animated bounceInDown">Brand Navigation Test</h1>

 <ul class="cd-accordion-menu animated fadeIn">
  <li class="has-children">
   <input type="checkbox" name ="group-1" id="group-1">
   <label for="group-1">About our brand</label>
   <ul>
    <li><span class="textDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed sagittis neque nec massa pharetra, sit amet rutrum quam 
    semper. Nulla malesuada dictum augue.<a class="internalLink" href="#">Click for more info</a>.</span></li>
         <li><a href="#0">Brand voice</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Our audiences</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Company message and our story</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Abraham Lincoln</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
   <input type="checkbox" name ="group-2" id="group-2">
   <label for="group-2">Brand guidelines</label>
   <ul>
    <li><span class="textDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed sagittis neque nec massa pharetra, sit amet rutrum quam 
    semper. Nulla malesuada dictum augue.<a class="internalLink" href="#">Want to know more</a>?</span></li>
    <li class="has-children">
     <input type="checkbox" name ="sub-group-3" id="sub-group-3">
     <label for="sub-group-3">Design guidelines</label>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#0">Logo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Tagline</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Typography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Color palette</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Image strategy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Iconography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Background textures</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Collateral systems</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Brand architecture</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Department identifiers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Signage</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-children">
     <input type="checkbox" name ="sub-group-3a" id="sub-group-3a">
     <label for="sub-group-3a">Writing guidelines</label>
     <ul>
      <li><span class="textDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Sed sagittis neque nec massa pharetra, sit amet rutrum quam 
      semper. Nulla malesuada dictum augue.</span></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Editorial standards</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Web standards</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Email signatures</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
   <input type="checkbox" name ="group-3" id="group-3">
   <label for="group-3">Templates</label>
   <ul>
    <li><span class="textDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed sagittis neque nec massa pharetra, sit amet rutrum quam 
    semper. Nulla malesuada dictum augue.</span></li>
    <li><a href="#0">PowerPoint templates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Stationary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Invitations, agendas and speaker bios</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
   <input type="checkbox" name ="group-4" id="group-4">
   <label for="group-4">Advertising</label>
   <ul>
    <li><span class="textDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed sagittis neque nec massa pharetra, sit amet rutrum quam 
    semper. Nulla malesuada dictum augue.</span></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
   <input type="checkbox" name ="group-5" id="group-5">
   <label for="group-5">Blog</label>
   <ul>
    <li><span class="textDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed sagittis neque nec massa pharetra, sit amet rutrum quam 
    semper. Nulla malesuada dictum augue.</span></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
   <input type="checkbox" name ="group-6" id="group-6">
   <label for="group-6">Brand support and FAQ</label>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#0">Third-party logo usage requirements</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Promotional Needs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Business cards and stationary requirements</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><span class="textDesc last">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed sagittis neque nec massa pharetra, sit amet rutrum quam 
    semper. Nulla malesuada dictum augue.</span></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul> <!-- cd-accordion-menu -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a little jQuery.

```
$(".cd-accordion-menu input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
      $(".cd-accordion-menu input[type='checkbox']:checked").not($(this)).each(function(){
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
      })
});
```

The way this accordion originally works is by using checkboxes and hiding them (with css). What determines whether or not the accordion is collapsed/expanded is the checkbox's checked attribute. So by setting all checkboxes' checked to false, with the exception of the one menu being expanded, it will collapse all other opened ones.

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/0z57yjer/

The code first attaches a click handler to all checkboxes inside the menu, and handles the click event. When a checkbox is clicked, it will look for all other sibling checkboxes, except itself, and it will turn the checked attribute to false.

**Note**: You do not need Modernizr for this to work, it is a pure CSS menu.

**Edit**: For your second question, about how to allow the sub-menus to still be displayed (I did not know this existed originally), I changed the script a little bit:

```
$(".cd-accordion-menu input[type='checkbox']:not([name*='sub'])").click(function(){
   ...
});
```

Notice I added the `:not([name*=sub'])`, this will exclude all checkboxes that are sub-menus from executing the inner code (unchecking everything).

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/0z57yjer/1/

Comment: Thanks Hanlet! Great help my friend. I appreciate it. Can you please address one concern I have? There is a nested folder that also opens more items. How would I address that so it opens and doesn't collapse. You will find it under Brand Guidelines. It's another accordion called Design guidelines that has several options underneath.

Comment: @KennethKerr I attempted to answer the second part. Look at my edit. Good luck.

Comment: | Thanks for the help. I was able to get that to work. Greatly appreciated! Take Care!